# Launching another Activity creates a blank screen and crashes

Tags: android, android-activity

> Update: Fixed, this was due to missing properties in views and my not knowing how to work the debugger :)

I'm really new to Android. I've just finished the Notepad tutorial and am making something similar (most of the code is exactly the same). The sequence of events I'm going through:

1. Debug app
2. Click Menu, which has the correct items
3. Click Insert, which opens a new Activity (GoalEdit)
4. I hit a breakpoint on the first line of `GoalEdit.onCreate` and get these warnings:
   a. (ActivityManager) Launch timeout has expired, giving up wake lock!
   b. (ActivityManager) Activity idle timeout for HistoryRecord{...}
5. I have a breakpoint at `setContentView` in `GoalEdit.onCreate` - after this is passed:
   a. ActivityThread.perfo: Source not found.

The relevant code is below:

**GoalsList.java**

```
/**
 * Add a menu to this activity
 */
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

    menu.add(0, INSERT_ID, 0, R.string.menu_insert);
    return true;
}

/**
 * Catch the menuItemSelected event
 */
@Override
public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case INSERT_ID:
        createGoal();
        return true;
    }

    return super.onMenuItemSelected(featureId, item);
}

/**
 * Open the Edit activity to create a new goal
 */
private void createGoal() {
    Intent i = new Intent(this, GoalEdit.class);
    startActivityForResult(i, ACTIVITY_CREATE);
}
```

**GoalEdit.java**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mDbGoals = new GoalDbTable(this);
    mDbGoals.open();

    setContentView(R.layout.goal_edit);

    mName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
    Button finishBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.finish);

    mRowId = (savedInstanceState == null) ? null :
        (Long) savedInstanceState.getSerializable(GoalDbTable.KEY_ROWID);
    if (mRowId == null) {
        Bundle extras  = getIntent().getExtras();
        mRowId = (extras != null) ? extras.getLong(GoalDbTable.KEY_ROWID)
                                  : null;
    }

    populateFields();

    finishBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            setResult(RESULT_OK);
            finish();
        }
    });
}

private void populateFields() {
    if (mRowId != null) {
        Cursor goal = mDbGoals.find(mRowId);
        startManagingCursor(goal);

        mName.setText(goal.getString(
                goal.getColumnIndexOrThrow(GoalDbTable.KEY_NAME)));
    }
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    populateFields();
}
```

I feel like the error is that it can't find GoalEdit (although it obviously can). Are there any obvious fubar's in my code (or other things I should check)?

**Edit:** Figured out how to use the debugger a bit better, had to press resume a few more times to show an exception.

**Exceptions**

```
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(741): 
  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity 
  ComponentInfo{com.rossmasters.mygoals/com.rossmasters.mygoals.GoalEdit}: 
    java.lang.RuntimeException: 
      Binary XML file line #9: You must supply a layout_width attribute.
```

I'm not sure which file that is referring to however, I've added `layout_width's` to each item.

Comment: Ross enable your logcat and you will get what is your problem,   Window > Show view > Other > Android > Logcat

Comment: Jorgesys: Yeah that's right. Seems the problem was to do with missing layout_width's in the views. Think I need to read up a little on using Eclipse's debugger :)

Comment: ;) yes missing property in your  goal_edit.xml layout

Comment: @Jorgesys: Post this as an answer and I'll accept it :)

Comment: Having a bit of an online clean-up :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ross enable your logcat and you will get what is your problem,

> Window > Show view > Other > Android >
>   Logcat

you are probably missin a property in your goal_edit.xml layout